# Can't Lazy Load Entity After Saving New Record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, poco

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 in my MVC 3.0 application. The application is an n-tier approach with my UI, Model, Classes, Services and Repository all put into separate projects within one solution. I also use a Unit of Work approach and Dependency Injection, therefore, I don't have access to the DbContext in the UI.

I have a two classes like below

```
public partial class Form
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int eventID { get; set; }
    public string sampleName { get; set; }

    public virtual Event GetEvent{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Event
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string eventName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my Controller, I add an instance of class Form like this

```
Form _form = new Form();
_form.eventID = 3;
_form.sampleName = "myString";

_formService.AddForm(_form);
_formService.SaveChanges(); //This calls the Unit of Work Commit
```

This works and inserts the record into the database. But then in the lines below the SaveChanges() call I try to lazy load the related Event class like this

```
string _eventName = _form.GetEvent.eventName;
```

But the value `_form.GetEvent` is always NULL. It looks like `GetEvent` has not been loaded.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the `GetEvent` property to `Event`, so that EF can infer the Foreign Key relationship (via `eventId`) following the usual [conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj679962.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you should access Context , and create a proxy instead of new Form ,so you can write a method in repository which you access Context ,and return type is Form class .

for more information see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711065/lazy-loading-not-working-after-savechanges-entity-framework);